# Does model.eval() placement matter in the code?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision

Might be a bit silly but I need to make sure this is correct. Does it matter if I place my code like this?:

```
model.eval()
with torch.no_grad():
```

Or can I get the same behaviour like this:

```
with torch.no_grad():
    model.eval()
```

I'm just wondering because I have a function that has model.eval() inside of it which goes inside of a loop where `with torch.no_grad():` is before it ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### both of them are correct, you just need to use the `model. eval()` Before you explore,

you should put the model in eval mode, both in general and so that batch norm
doesn't cause you issues and is using its eval statistics

Comment: so placement doesn't matter, it's just to make sure batch norm and dropout is not active?

Comment: @TSRAI yes you need to stop the dropout and batch norm layers and some other specific parts model. eval() take care of all that for you

Answer (score 1):

If `model.eval()` ever throws an exception the behavior won’t be the same. That’s because `with` will attempt to close whatever was returned by `torch.no_grad()` when an exception is thrown under its scope.

`with` is a handy way to make sure you clean up resources even when things blow up.

Comment: ah ok, how would I know if ```model.eval()``` would ever throw an exception? would the code break? It appears to run seamlessly so far. Would it be better to define a property ```@torch.no_grad()``` over the function?

Comment: You have to read eval() and see if it sometimes throws, or calls something that does.

Comment: how would you do that?